# jmeter hazelcast

Tags: java, request, jmeter

Написал `java request` для `Jmeter`,который получает объект по ключу из `hazelcast`. Объект я вижу только в логах Jmeter.
Вопросы:

1. Как получать стандартные метрики `jmeter` типа `Latency`, `Connect Timt` и т.п. в в лисенере `"View Results in Table"`, `"Samary Report"`...?
2. Мне конкретно нужно время получения объекта по ключу, как это реализовать в коде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас имеется что-то вроде:

```
@Override
public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
    SampleResult result = new SampleResult();
    //some hazelcast related code
    return result();
}
```

У этого самого [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) имеются все необходимые методы, например:

- [SampleResult.sampleStart()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#sampleStart--) - время старта
- [SampleResult.sampleEnd()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#sampleEnd--) - время окончания

То есть **Response Time** - будет равным `sampleEnd() - sampleStart()`, обычно это время от того как JMeter начал выполнять запрос до получения последнего байта ответа

Аналогично для Connect Time / Latency:

- [SampleResult.setConnectTime()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setConnectTime-long-)
- [SampleResult.setLatency()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setLatency-long-)

Для [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) JMeter измеряет все автоматически, т.е.

```
Response Time = Connect Time + Latency + Time to last byte
```

В случае кастомного запроса вам придется самим определять что вы хотите записывать как Connect Time и Latency

Информацию о терминах можно посмотреть [здесь](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) и [здесь](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420385-Glossary)